# Building customized URLs in WordPress with add_query_var

Tags: wordpress

I do have a problem with add_query_args in generating urls on my website. I do have a product detail page with some info from a post. I created some advanced custom fields (ACF) to distinguish between some types of this product. A type is a repeater field in the ACF, so I can add more types to one product.

So I display first the common information from that post and then I display (in a loop) those ACF type fields with a link:

[product]

- type 1 (more info)
- type 2 (more info)
- type 3 (more info)

I also created an empty post/page with a slug: more_info_page and a template on which I will display all the detailed info for that post with that one type.

The (more info) should point to that page with the post ID and the number of the ACF type. In the loop I have an index, so the number is there. With that number I can get the info from the ACF field (I hope).

As far as my knowledge at this moment goes, I can create an url like this:

```
$mylink = esc_url( 
    add_query_arg( array (

        'post_id' => $post->ID, 
        'type'    => $type_idx,

    ), site_url( '/more_info_page/' ) 
));

<a href="<?php echo $mylink; ?>">more info</a>
```

I do indeed get those links like:

```
/more_info_page/?post_id=300&type=0

/more_info_page/?post_id=300&type=1

/more_info_page/?post_id=300&type=2
```

The links are there and the first one indeed opens the right template page in which I can see the query vars. But... the other links do not link to the right page. The URL is just the same as the first one, only the type number differs. But it will not display/load my /more_info_page like the first link.

I do not have a clue what goes wrong. Is my use of add_query_arg wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to include the vars in functions.php, like this:

```
// Add custom query vars
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars', 10, 1 );

function my_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'type';

    return $vars;
}
```

And the name was not unique in my case, so I had to change the name too.